# How to make all the icons in one level?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X6SJ.jpg)

see the red arrow, here the Instagram icon is not on one level, how to make them in one level?, See the screenshot?

See with the website https://www.gloweasy.com/

Comment: You'll have to provide the code if you want us to help.

Comment: Have you fixed this? It looks fine in Chrome.

Comment: No not fixed, You can see the website https://www.gloweasy.com/,

See the Instagram icon is a little gone upward.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to replicate this issue. If you inspect your `social_wrap` class you will see all social icons are aligned properly. Each `li` item is also 23x20px, including the Instagram image, so this isn't an issue unless you can provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

I find them all aligned. But still, if you think there is some alignment, then use `line-height` property.